# Priority for HTTP over SSH

Tags: ssh, scp

My file server (Ubuntu) on the internet runs OpenSSH, where users upload and download files using scp or WinSCP. At the same time, the server runs some web applications (http), which need higher priority.

Is there a way to give HTTP priority over SSH file transfer? If not, can I limit SSH bandwidth?

Comment: Do you know what might help? how about telling us what operating system you're running on? Windows, Linux, OSX, Solaris etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you have cooperative users, you can limit the files transfer using: `-l limit` in `scp`. For more info, see `man scp`.

Otherwise, you need to implement some traffic shaping using `tc`. I am talking about Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tool called trickle to slow down the traffic on SSH - it's really useful, I use it to control the speeds of remote backups and such.

Comment: Can you give an example?